# Divergence theorem with non smooth functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lipschitz-functions

How do you extend the classical multivariable integration by parts formula for functions with countably many discontinuities?

Is the result still true? Can I use an approximating sequence?

Answer (score -2):

It is true. Here's another way of seeing it. By the divergence theorem,
$$
\int_\Omega div(f\phi)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\partial \Omega}f\phi\cdot \nu\,\mathrm{d}S,
$$
where $\nu$ is the outward unit normal. Since $\phi$ has compact support, the right hand side equals zero. Then component wise, this means
$$
\int_\Omega \partial_i (f\phi)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_\Omega \partial_i(f)\phi\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_\Omega f\partial_i(\phi)\,\mathrm{d}x=0.
$$